# Eclipse Orion PHP plugin

Tags: php, code-completion, ibm-cloud, eclipse-orion, devops

So for a project I need to check if I'm able to get code completion working for Eclipse Orion (on the IBM DevOps Services WebIDE) when coding in PHP. There's a default plugin available but it only provides syntax highlighting. Code completion is the deciding factor this time.

Just googling around I've found some plugins here and there in various git repos but they seem to be for an outdated version of Orion, hence not usable here.

So, just a quick throw out if someone is using IBM DevOps Services WebIDE (or some Eclipse Orion implementation) with a PHP plugin with code-completion? Preferably a link to installation steps since I need to educate a programming class on how to set everything up from a clean slate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orion's Go language plug-in provides a straight-forward example of contributing content assist via a plugin, see http://git.eclipse.org/c/orion/org.eclipse.orion.client.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.orion.client.ui/web/plugins/languages/go?id=R7_0 .  To make something similar for PHP you would create a plug-in with the same shape that defines at least the "orion.edit.contentAssist" service, and then install it in your Orion/WebIDE on its Settings-Plugins page (point it at your plugin's .html file).